# Keep permalinks in Wordpress

Tags: permalinks

Is there any way to set my permalinks to keep their exact link. If I have a post like this one http://blog.rigo.ro/?p=11, then I would like that every time I edit the post to keep this link.

I have installed the Revision Control plugin and I set it to do not keep revisions. Any ideea how to do this? I want to keep this format of links.

Edit:

I took a look again, the permalinks keep their links, but every time I edit it adds a new version to the database and the next post will have a higher number. If I edit my current post for 3 times (blog.rigo.ro/?p=11) the next post will be blog.rigo.ro/?p=14.

Now, my question is how can I keep all my post and edits clean, one post/more edits = one entry in the database, so if I have. 10 post on my site and I edit them, I would like that my permalinks to be from 1 to 10.

PS: I don't want to edit my database manually, is there any plugin to do this?

Comment: The simple way is to not use the page ID in your permalink. In my WordPress settings, I can set it to take the title of the page as the permalink.

Comment: @RandolphWest - you should post that as an answer, I think

Comment: I'm not sure i follow. I've never seen a fresh WP install change id-based slugs on post/page edits. Actually, i've never seen it change ids, ever. Are you sure this isn't being caused by any other plugin?

Comment: @moraleida, the way OP describes the behaviour is correct.

Comment: @RandolphWest re-read the question, and you're right. At first i thought the same post was having its ids changed from 11 to 14, according to the edits.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to not use the page ID in your permalink.

In my WordPress settings, I can set it to take the title of the page as the permalink. In my example below, I use "Post name".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to do it in two steps:

1. Create one flag value on your database, that will hold the real post-count as an int
2. Hook to the `wp_insert_post_data` filter and change the slug as it's generated

The snippet below itercepts every `wp_insert_post data` call to change the regular slugs to 1+ the last id referenced on the database;

Note that you need to initialize the 'last_post_number' on the db calling update_option at least once before running this.

```
function wpse_permalink_change($data) {

        // IMPORTANT: before running the code below, check if this is a new post, 
        // or a post edit and discard post edits.

        // Retrieve the last post number saved  
        $i = get_option( 'last_post_number' );
        $i++;

        // Set it as your post_name
        $data['post_name'] = $i;

        // Update the last post number  
        update_option('last_post_number', $i)
        return $data;

}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','wpse_permalink_change',10,2);
```

This is untested and kinda hackish, but i might dive into making it a plugin if it's of any interest. :)

Also: this only helps if your main concern are the permalinks, no the real database primary_keys.